# Usage of ITemplate in custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to figure out if I can use the `ITemplate` interface in a custom control. Here is what I've done so far.

```
public class Tooltip : Control
{
    public ITemplate ContentTemplate { get; set; }

    protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        base.CreateChildControls();

        var ctrl = new HtmlGenericControl("a");

        if (ContentTemplate != null)
        {
            ContentTemplate.InstantiateIn(ctrl);
        }

        this.Controls.Add(ctrl);
    }
}
```

The asp.net control usage

```html
<gc:Tooltip runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        hello
    </ContentTemplate>
</gc:Tooltip>
```

The idea is that it should return something like this

```html
<a>hello</a>
```

But the result looks like this

```html
<ContentTemplate>
  hello
</ContentTemplate>
<a></a>
```

It does include the template tags and seem to ignore whatever I do.

Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was inheriting from the wrong class, when switching to WebControl it started working

```
public class Tooltip : WebControl
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.itemplate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and do exactly as they already said.

You missed this:

```
  [
      PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty),
      TemplateContainer(typeof(TemplateItem))
  ]
```

And also you should set this part on your class:

```
[ParseChildren(true)]
```

Comment: Thanks, I did have a look at that but it suggested I should create an external control and I was looking for a solution where I could implement the template directly. Inheriting from WebControl instead of Control solved my issue.